# How to make many words all trigger the same thing

Tags: javascript, discord.js

What i want is those three words, can, is, and was, to trigger the same bit of code. If can, is or was is in the text i do not want the first bit to run but the second bit instead.

```
bot.on ('message', function (message){
const words = message.content.split(' ');

if(words.includes('sans'))
{
    const words = message.content.split(' ');
    if(!message.content.includes ('can', 'is', 'was'))
    {
        if(message.author.bot) return;
        var chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); 
        if(chance == 0)
        {
            message.channel.send('<:annoying_sans:520355361425981440>');    
        }
        if(chance == 1)
        {
            message.channel.send('<:sans:519723756403425294>');    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); 
if(chance == 0)
{
    message.channel.send('Maybe.');    
}
if(chance == 1)
{
    message.channel.send('Yes.');    
}
if(chance == 2)
{
    message.channel.send('No.');    
}

}

}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

first of all you're creating an array called "words" which you are never using.

furthermore you will have to iterate over every item within the array to check each string inside.

also, you're not providing us with the code that should be triggered if the message contains any of the three words, but what would trigger if they are NOT included.

in addition, you're creating a constant variable with the same name twice.

```
bot.on ('message', function (message){
const words = message.content.split(' ');
if(words.includes('sans')){
    var questionwords = ['can', 'is', 'was',];
    for (i in questionwords) {
        if(words.includes(questionwords[i])) {
            if(message.author.bot) return;
            message.channel.send('<:download:519723756403425294>');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

take this as a guideline and don't just copypaste it

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
function includesQuestionWords(content, questionWords = ['can', 'is', 'was',]) {
    return questionWords.some(word => content.includes(word));
}
```

`Array.prototype.some` will execute a function for each element in an array and return true if even one of them is true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the value is coming in is, but I have written some code below which I think you were trying achieve. It will show you how to search for can, is or was. Both my solutions use a for in loop. You use for in loops to loop through objects.

```
var sentence = 'can I go for a walk?';

checkIfQuestion(sentence);

function checkIfQuestion(str){
    var newWords = str.split(" ");
    var questionWords = ['can', 'is', 'was'];
    for(var char in newWords){ // Look at all the keys in the newWords object
        for(let i = 0; i < questionWords.length; i++){
            if(newWords[char] === questionWords[i]){
                console.log("It's a question!!");
                // Add your event here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above does not use .includes. Includes behind the scenes still loops, however you do not have to write out the for loop. That code snippet is below uses includes.

```
var sentence = 'can I go for a walk?';

checkIfQuestion(sentence);
function checkIfQuestion(str){
    var newWords = str.split(" ");
    var questionWords = ['can', 'is', 'was'];
    for(var char in newWords){ // Look at all the keys in the newWords object
        if(questionWords.includes(newWords[char])){
            console.log('it is a question');
            // Add your event here
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully one of these snippets helps you complete your function :)